# Where should propTypes for navigationOptions inside createBottomTabNavigator be defined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, react-proptypes

I just applied airbnb, prettier, react/prettier and all the linting. I still cannot get around this error[1] because I do not understand correctly where should propTypes should be declared for "inner functions" as this one.

I am not giving those parameters, nor am I defining them. They come from [createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html) as I can read in the doc. So, **how should I have a say in what props are required for `tabBarIcon` and which are not** in the destructuring of these?[2]

**UPDATE**

[1] The error is a linting error. The code executes just fine.

[2] We can of course fiddle around a bit to get it working and avoid the errors but my aim is to understand how it works and why is it giving the errors back, being that [snippet](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance) the official example.

```js
export const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    ...
);

export const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStackNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        // Getting error here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // 'focused' is missing in props validationeslint(react/prop-types)
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = 'ios-home';
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = 'ios-cog';
        }
        return (
          <IconComponent //
            name={iconName}
            color={tintColor}
            size={25}
          />
        );
      },
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      // activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
    },
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      isStoreLoading: false,
      store: createStore(rootReducer)
    };
  }

  ...

  componentDidMount(){...}

  ...

  render() {
    const { store, isStoreLoading } = this.state;
    if (isStoreLoading) {
      return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can remove `let IconComponent = Ionicons;` and `IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;` and use `<Ionicons />`

Comment: how would that help me to know where should propTypes for navigationOptions inside createBottomTabNavigator be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to define prop-types for an inner function like this, you need to move it outside of the navigator.

```js
const MyTabBarIcon = ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor, navigation }) => {
    // [...]
}

MyTabBarIcon.propTypes = {
    focused: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    tintColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    horizontal: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Then your TabNavigator becomes:

```js
// [...]
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: props => <MyTabBarIcon {...props} navigation={navigation} />,
  // [...]
});
// [...]
```

Comment: `navigation` then would not be used, and not defined. As it is used in the `tabBarIcon` method.

Comment: You can just add it as a property. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Not really satisfied with the linting and the solution, I feel it is kind of cheating. Haven't found an alternative though, and yours seems to be just enough to do it "the propper way".